# Tribonacci Numbers Satisfying Certain Conditions

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, fibonacci-numbers, square-numbers

---

Here is my question that I tried to solve:

Let $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ and

$\displaystyle \frac{1}{1-x-x^2-x^3}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n x^n$ $ \quad $ holds.

According to above find all positive integers that satisfy the equaility

$a_n=(n+1)^2$

---

**My attempt:**
In the first place, i sensed that there is no n positive integer that holds the desired. With that starting point, I remembered that with using tribonacci numbers which are  denoted by $T_n$ that satisfy

$T_0=T_1=0, T_2=1$ and for $\, \,n \geq 3 $ $\quad$ $ T_n=T_{n-1}+T_{n-2}+T_{n-3}$

the power series converges the function which is desired ;

$\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty \,T_n \, \, x^n=\frac{1}{1-x-x^2-x^3}$

So I started to check is there any numbers that satisfy the equatily $\,$$T_n = a_n$ $\, $ for $ n \geq 1$

$T_1= 0  \neq 4=(1+1)^2$

$T_2= 1  \neq 9=(2+1)^2$

$T_3= 1  \neq 16=(3+1)^2$

$T_4= 2  \neq 25=(4+1)^2$

$T_5= 4  \neq 36=(5+1)^2$

$T_6= 7  \neq 49=(6+1)^2$

$T_7= 13  \neq 64=(7+1)^2$

$T_8= 24 \neq 81=(8+1)^2$

$T_9= 44  \neq 100=(9+1)^2$

$T_{10}= 81  \neq 121=(10+1)^2$

$T_{11}= 149  \neq 144=(11+1)^2$

$T_{12}= 274  \neq 169=(12+1)^2$

$T_{13}= 504  \neq 196=(13+1)^2$

$T_{14}= 927  \neq 225=(14+1)^2$

$T_{15}= 3136  \neq 256=(15+1)^2$

and so on.

I sensed that for every  $n >10 $

$T_n > (n+1)^2$.

If i could show that inequaility my problem is solved. But here is where is stuck. Thought that maybe I could use Binet's formulas for tribonacci numbers to show

$ \displaystyle \lim _{n \to \infty} \frac{a_n}{T_n}=0$

but it is not the answer that I seek for(Maybe there are positive integers that holds)

It is not necessary to continue solving the problem the way i started - other way of solutions is helpful also- but i want to solve in my way. Thanks in advance for your help and tips.

Comment: I am sorry to differ because Mathematica gives: $(1-x-x^2-x^3)^{-1}=1+x+2x^2+4x^3+7x^4+13x^5+O(x^6)+..$

Answer (score 1):

Induction works after the initial segment: If $n>4$ and $T_k>(k+1)^2$ for $k=n-1$ and for $k=n-2$, then 
$$ T_n-(n+1)^2\ge n^2+(n-1)^2-(n+1)^2=n^2-4n>0$$

Comment: I didn't get the process while writing down  $T_n - (n+1)^2 \geq n^2 + (n-1)^2 -(n+1)^2$ .Could you explain in details?